# Cross references broken in Lyx master document

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

I've got a child document which contains cross references. When I export the child document to PDF, the cross references are fine. However, when I export the master document to PDF the cross references are broken and appear like:

(see ??sub:WMS-Module on page 42).

When I click the reference it goes to the correct place, and 42 is the correct page number, but it doesn't display the reference!

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Without an example of your input, this is going to be more or less impossible to solve. As such, it looks 'too localized': ask for reopening after editing in some more info.

Answer (score 2):

I think I had the same problem as you. Equations in child documents would be referenced as (??) using EqRef and revtex. When I changed the child document include type from Include to Input in the master document this was fixed, but this has the side effect of starting new child documents on the same page rather than a new page which may not be what you want.